# having problems with provisioning profile with xcode 4.2 and new mac

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I am getting the

```
"xcode could not find a valid private-key certificate pair for this profile in your keychain"
```

[image]

error when trying to run an app on a device. I have moved to a new machine since I signed up but just downloaded certificate which appears in Keychain Access app to be correct. What would be the best way to troubleshoot? Is there a way to see a log of what Xcode / device / Keychain are trying to do and the error thrown? The user experience for this is honestly terrible (esp for something you pay for).

Comment: did you just copy the certificate from older machine or did you do the proper export of the private key?

Comment: So - I'm redownloaded certificate from iOS provisioning portal. I'm don't have the key locally (I think) and access to other computer is a little limited. Ideallly, don't want to have to go there. Is it possible to not have the private key from originally setting this up and making it work?

Comment: Private key can be obtained only from the mac where the CSR was generated. The only way to correctly install the certificate is to export the private key from the original Mac and add to the keychain of the new one. If you don't have access to original mac, you can try revoking the certificate from portal and requesting a new one from your current mac

Comment: So I revoked certificate, followed CSR steps. Apple's process on this is really ugly. I'm also the team admin. Should I delete these from keychain?

Comment: Yes. Delete the old ones from your keychain as well as the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a new machine you need to generate a new certificate and upload to provisioning portal or get your old generated certificate.

Comment: the above error is from a certificate I just downloaded for provisioning portal via iOS Provisioning Portal so I don't think problem with cert - the issue I think is with private key

Comment: Its because you need to generate a new private key and upload it again to the provisioning portal.

Answer (score 0):

Vin and Alexandre.soli have it right.

To correctly sign a provisioning profile you need to have the private key in you keychain that matches the public key in the provisioning profile.

So either:

1. Look for the private key on your old machine, export it (you need admin passwords to do this) and manually transfer the key to your new build machine. Double click on it to install (more passwords at this point)

or:

2: Generate a new certificate (on the machine you wish to build on) and upload it to iTunes thus ensuring that a new private key is resident in your keychain.